# please give me advice with django admin

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin, django-3.0

I'm new with python and Django. I know a lot about the Codeigniter framework and there if you want to create a project like an eCommerce you must create an admin panel with template and function for the backend. when I was creating backend I was adding functions for the admin panel where all functions were for adding some informations in the database. so when I start with Django I saw that there was an integrated admin panel which can be modified but I have a question can I create app for Django which will be admin panel of my project

Comment: You can create an admin app. Just create a page (or multiple pages or an app) for admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, definitely man. Django provides its own admin panel and it is really very helpful, you can customize it also as per yours need.

But if you want to make your own `admin panel` then you can do it. You can create a separate `app` for that. And then you have to manage `templates` as per your admin panel design and apply all functionality in `views.py`. And all `URLs` which will be used for the admin panel, should be mentioned in `urls.py`.